# How do I determine if an object implements a method in Perl?

Tags: perl, reflection, polymorphism, oop

I've got a polymorphic array of objects which implement two (informal) interfaces. I want to be able to differentiate them with reflection along the lines of:

```
if (hasattr(obj, 'some_method')) {
    # `some_method` is only implemented by one interface.
    # Now I can use the appropriate dispatch semantics.
} else {
    # This must be the other interface.
    # Use the alternative dispatch semantics.
}
```

Maybe something like this works?:

```
if (*ref(obj)::'some_method') {
    # ...
```

I have difficulty telling when the syntax will try to invoke a subroutine and when it will return a subroutine reference. I'm not too familiar with package symbol tables ATM and I'm just trying to hack something out. :-)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
use Scalar::Util qw(blessed);
if( blessed($obj) and $obj->can('some_method') ){ 

}
```

"can" here is a method inherited by all classes from [UNIVERSAL](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Default-UNIVERSAL-methods) . Classes *can* override this method, but its not a good idea to.

Also,  "can" returns a reference to the function, so you can do:

```
$foo->can('some_method')->( $foo , @args );
```

or

```
my $sub = $foo->can('some_method'); 
$foo->$sub( @args );
```

- [Scalar::Util](http://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util)
- [Perl Objects on perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Default-UNIVERSAL-methods)

**Edit** Updated Chain Syntax, thanks to Brian Phillips

Comment: Is `can` a reserved method name in some way, or do you just happen to shoot yourself in the foot if you implement it?

Comment: Don't forget you need to explicitly pass the object in to the function reference returned by can: $foo->can('some_method')->($foo, @args).  Alternatively, my $sub = $foo->can('some_method'); $foo->$sub(@args);

Comment: A general injunction against overriding `can` is a bit strong.  There are good and important reasons to do it.